# How to redirect to upper directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a VPS and use PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.2 on a 64bit CentOS.
I have many domains on this VPS that used a shared library named `core`.
each Domain redirect to a directory with same name in apache html's directory. to be clear, this directory's structure is like this:

```
cd /var/www/html/
ls

core
site1_dir
site2_dir
site3_dir
site4_dir
...
```

for example `http://www.site1.com` root directory is `/var/www/html/site1_dir`

but there are many files and libraries in core that can't be address like this:

```
http://www.site1.com/../core/etc
```

so i created an empty folder, named `core` in each site's directory and i want to put a .htaccess file in them, in ordor to access core contents in each domains. for example:

`http://www.site1.com/core/js/script.js` must be a direct link from `/var/www/html/core/js/script.js` .

creating this .htaccess file is my question, and any other given options will be useful for me.

Comment: Any domain cannot access file outside DocumentRoot and that is indeed the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a symlink in each dir to the upper core dir and then work the files that way.